# Display a message in jQuery only once when I submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

When I submit my form, I display a message in jQuery.

I want it appears only once when I submit more than once

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    if ($('#title').val() != '' && $('#comment').val() != '')
        $('form').append($('<span>').text('Bug sent').delay(4000).fadeOut(600));
    else
        $('form').append($('<span>').text('Fields are empty').delay(4000).fadeOut(600));

return false;
});
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/bUS8e/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply remove any existing `span`s in the form: http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/bUS8e/1/.

```
$('form span').remove();
```

Note that this would also remove any other, irrelevant `span`s which you might not want to have removed. In that case, you can add a class to the message `span`s you add, and use `$('form span.message').remove();` so that only those message `span`s get removed.

Answer (score 2):

Check if `$('form').text()` contains "Bug sent"?
i.e.

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    if ($('#title').val() != '' && $('#comment').val() != '')
        if (!/Bug sent/.test($('form').text()) {
            $('form').append($('<span>').text('Bug sent').delay(4000).fadeOut(600));
        }
    else
        $('form').append($('<span>').text('Fields are empty').delay(4000).fadeOut(600));

return false;
});
```

Comment: `str.test` is not a function. What library are you using perhaps?

Comment: I had edited this before your comment, but yes - I did indeed get my RegExp and String variables the wrong way round. Luckily I spotted my own mistake and fixed it ;)

Answer (score 2):

Remove all spans when the user submits the form. Then add them again (if necessary):

[Like this](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/bUS8e/3/)

Answer (score 1):

You could add the `span` to the HTML code and give it an ID. And instead of appending a new `span` everytime, you just reuse the existing one by addressing it via its ID.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `div` (or any other element) to your form and use `$('div').html([YOUR STUFF])` instead of `$('form').append([YOUR STUFF])`.

Answer (score 0):

You should clear the parent element before:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    if ($('#title').val() != '' && $('#comment').val() != '')
        $('form').empty().append($('<span>').text('Bug sent').delay(4000).fadeOut(600));
    else
        $('form').empty().append($('<span>').text('Fields are empty').delay(4000).fadeOut(600));

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Not sure if that's the best solution since all `input`s would get removed as well.

Comment: Sorry, you should add a <div id="message"></div> before and use this one.